# Powermock: How to mock a private method inside a static class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

Let's say that I have a utility class like this:

`public final class NumberUtility{`

`public static int getNumberPlusOne(int num){`

```
   return doSomethingFancyInternally(num);
```

`}`

`private static int doSomethingFancyInternally(int num){`

```
      //Fancy code here...

  return num;
```

`}`

`}`

Assuming that I don't change the class's structure, how do mock the `doSomethingFancyInternally()` method with the use of Powermock?

Answer (score 0):

Why you cannot mock `getNumberPlusOne` method with PowerMock ?
Private method shouldn't be visible in tests.

For example someone change internal implementation of private method ( change method name even) then your test will fail.

Comment: Then alter the test to make it pass? Powermock is able to mock private methods with the use of 'spies'. It's just that I can't access the private method inside a final class.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `java reflection` to access `private` method in a `class`. So similar way you can test this `private` method.

Answer (score 0):

Usually to test such a situations the Bypass encapsulation technique can be used. Here is the example of this: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/BypassEncapsulation. Frankly speaking it just hacks the class privacy with use of the java reflection API, so you're not forced to change your class strcuture to test it.

Comment: @MiguelPortugal, No, I don't have any trustable recent documentation. But I drilled down the source files and it seems they renameв the class `WhiteBox` to `WhiteBoxImpl`, which do excatly the same thing described in the article.

Answer (score 0):

This should help-> Mocking a private static method on a class

http://avricot.com/blog/index.php?post/2011/01/25/powermock-%3A-mocking-a-private-static-method-on-a-class

Here's my code for your class. I modified your CUT too.

TEST CLASS:

```
import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)    
@PrepareForTest({ NumberUtility.class })
public class NumberUtilityTest {

// Class Under Test
NumberUtility cut;

@Before
public void setUp() {

    // Create a new instance of the service under test (SUT).
    cut = new NumberUtility();

    // Common Setup
    // TODO
}

/**
 * Partial mocking of a private method.
 * 
 * @throws Exception
 * 
 */
@Test
public void testGetNumberPlusOne1() throws Exception {

    /* Initialization */
    PowerMock.mockStaticPartial(NumberUtility.class,
            "doSomethingFancyInternally");
    NumberUtility partialMockCUT = PowerMock.createPartialMock(
            NumberUtility.class, "doSomethingFancyInternally");
    Integer doSomethingFancyInternallyOutput = 1;
    Integer input = 0;

    /* Mock Setup */
    PowerMock
            .expectPrivate(partialMockCUT, "doSomethingFancyInternally",
                    EasyMock.isA(Integer.class))
            .andReturn(doSomethingFancyInternallyOutput).anyTimes();

    /* Activate the Mocks */
    PowerMock.replayAll();

    /* Test Method */
    Integer result = NumberUtility.getNumberPlusOne(input);

    /* Asserts */
    Assert.assertEquals(doSomethingFancyInternallyOutput, result);
    PowerMock.verifyAll();

}

}
```

CUT:
    public final class NumberUtility{

```
public static Integer getNumberPlusOne(Integer num){

return doSomethingFancyInternally(num);} 

private static Integer doSomethingFancyInternally(Integer num){

  //Fancy code here...

return num;} 

}
```

Comment: It will be impossible to create another instance of NumberUtility since it's a static final class.